# String index out of range python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function for a text rpg game that would print on terminal everything that is in specific marker, but I keep getting this error message:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Marked text in a file looks like this:

> |d0Dyspergator:
>   "Pulvis es et in pulverem revertis"
>   Raz na dwie walki i tylko raz w walce pozwala na uniknięcie następnego ataku przeciwnika
>   poprzez chwilowe zamienienie Cię w atomowy pył.|

where the pipe and first two symbols after it begin the marker, next pipe ends it.
Here is the code:

```
def bard(paragraph, point, file):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as w:
        d = w.read()
        index = 0
        tab = []
        frag = 0
        while frag == 0:
            if d[index] == '|'and d[index + 1] == paragraph and d[index + 2] == point:
                while d[index+3] != '|' and index + 3 <= len(d):
                    tab.append(d[index+3])
                    index += 1
                frag += 1
            else:
                index += 1
        a = ''.join(tab)
        print(a)
    return
```

I would be very thankful for any help, I am new to programming and I probably made a stupid mistake.

Comment: You are accessing a list behind its data. Here `if d[index] == '|'and d[index + 1] == paragraph and d[index + 2]` you add 1 and 2 to the index - if index ever reaches `len(d)-2` or more, you access behind it. Use print statements to figure it out and adapt your logic.

Comment: What should be the result in `a`? and why do you not return it?

Comment: The result I'm seeking is printinting the whole text in the marker. But I see now that I have logic errors, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do pattern matching on text. Ever heard of [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

It is exactly what they are build for:

```
text = """This is some text.
|2. second 
thing| more text
|3. thingding is after the marker and this text also.
This texts ends what I want| and this text should not be found..
also not found."""
with open("t.txt","w") as  f: 
    f.write(text)
```

Program:

```
with open("t.txt") as r:
    data = r.read()

import re
pattern = r'\|\d+\..*?\|'
k = re.findall(pattern,data,re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

print(k)
```

Output:

```
['|2. second \nthing|', 
 '|3. thingding is after the marker and this text also.\nThis texts ends what I want|']
```

The pattern `r'\|\d+\..*?\|'` I use looks for:

```
\|          matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\d+         matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    +           Quantifier — one to unlimited times, as many as possible
\.          matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
.*?         matches any character 
    *?          Quantifier — zero to unlimited times, as few as possible 
\|          matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
```

You can play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/65R2gq/1/

If you only need the text, you can use capturing groups - change the pattern to

```
pattern = r'\|\d+\.(.*?)\|'
```

to get

```
[' second \nthing', 
 ' thingding is after the marker and this text also.\nThis texts ends what I want']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a) this data structure with the piles and initial two (and exactly two) characters is a format you have developed yourself, and you control that it is consistently used, then you don't really need to go to any lengths least of all resort to [regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

```py
foo = '|d0Dyspergator: "Pulvis es et in pulverem revertis" Raz na dwie walki i tylko raz w walce pozwala na uniknięcie następnego ataku przeciwnika poprzez chwilowe zamienienie Cię w atomowy pył.|'
foo.split('|')[1][2:]
'Dyspergator: "Pulvis es et in pulverem revertis" Raz na dwie walki i tylko raz w walce pozwala na uniknięcie następnego ataku przeciwnika poprzez chwilowe zamienienie Cię w atomowy pył.'
```